# change automatically to next ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

**Following Situation.**

In a storyboard i have two ViewControllers. **ViewController_1** and **ViewController_2**. When the first **ViewController_1** opens and the viewdidload void did load, how can I move automatically to the next **ViewController_2** after a certain time(*which I can adjust*) without any user intervention? I'm using this self call up for my method:

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(toNewViewController:) withObject:nil 
afterDelay:timeInSeconds];
```

But I'm not sure, how to write the method with the view controller to view controller transition. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a segue (Arrow from one View to another) in your Storyboard from your first to your second view.

Then you need to call in your `toNewViewController` Method:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameOfYourSegue" sender:self];
```

This call will perform the transition from your first view to your second.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll have to create a function which will present your second viewcontroller.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:certainTime target:self selector:@selector(presentnextView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)presentnextView
{
    ViewController *secondView=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:secondView animated:YES completion:nil];
    [secondView release];
}
```

Comment: You can use the same thing without NSTimer, like you were doing using [performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]. It will work fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may also need this to intercept controller transfer and setup your target view controller:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nameOfYourSegue"]) {
                /* In my case its navigation controller, for you it may be different */
                UINavigationController *navi = [segue destinationViewController];
                ComposeViewController *compose = [navi.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
                compose->delegate = self;
                compose.login = self.login;
                compose.name = self.name;
        }
}
```